# Require suggestions for writing telugu font through english letters typing( english keyboard) in android app

Tags: android, fonts, translation

I would like to develop an meme android app in which I require English to Telugu conversion API.
When I type letters in English language that has to be converted and displayed right away in Telugu font.  For example i type "hyderabad" there should be instant conversion display of "హైదరాబాద్". 
Any suggestions or code snippets or at least any API resources are appreciable.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it is not working properly"? Is it not translating the text correctly? Or is the display of the converted text not correct? Can you post the code and input/output text you're currently using?

Comment: No. Actually that is not the one we want to use.Google translate API converts our English sentence into appropriate Telugu sentence. What i want is if we type "hyderabad "in english the telugu font "హైదరాబాద్" should be displayed. please give us any idea or resource

Comment: So if I understand correctly: the API is working as it should (text is correctly translated), but your problem has to do with displaying the translated text? Which version of Android? Telugu is supposed to be supported in core Android since Jellybean (4.2), though specific vendor distributions may have stripped some support, which would prevent correct display.

Comment: please read the question once again as i think you didn't get it correctly so i have edited question so that please check it again.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. So you are basically asking how to use the Google Translate API? Have you already looked through the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started)? There is plenty of example code there.